# Is it possible integration test between applications in Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test, google-cloud-test-lab

I have an flutter application that needs to integrate/redirect to another application through universal links. The other applications is not mine.

Is it possible to simulate this integration/redirection using Firebase Test Lab?